# Using codeigniter input library in safe

Tags: php, codeigniter, security

Genereally I'm using codeigniter input library like that =>

```
$insert = $this->input->post();
```

I wonder is it safe or must I use like that? =>

```
$name = $this->input->post('name');
$gsm = $this->input->post('gsm');
$insert = array(
  'name' => $name,
  'gsm' => $gsm
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the POST method safe, then also provide second parameter:

**For your first method:**

```
$this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
```

This will return all the POST items with XSS filter.

**...And if you want to use second method:**

```
$this->input->post('input_field_name', TRUE);
```

This will return the POST item with the name of 'input_field_name' with XSS filter applied.

You can read more about codeigniter input class and XSS security **[HERE](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/input.html)**.

Comment: $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); makes all the input field names safe? for example is name = "user['gsm']" will be safe?

Comment: Yes, considering Cross Site Scripting Hacks, this will be safe to use. Once you have applied the `$this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);`, the array you will receive will be safe.